# use jQuery in Backbone.js through event, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm trying to get a click event to execute a jQuery action in a Backbone view.

This is my Backbone view

```
class Movieseat.Views.MovieseatsIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['movieseats/index']

  initialize: ->
    @render()

  render: ->
    @$el.html @template()

  event: -> 
    "click #click": "showtext"

  showtext: ->
    console.log "text"

  el: "#container"
```

My template,

```
<div id="click">Click</div>
```

And the Rails view for my homepage

```
:javascript 
  $(function() { 
    new Movieseat.Views.MovieseatsIndex
  });
```

When I click the `#click` div I'm trying to get the `showText` function to work and show "text" in my console. But I'm getting no result in the console.

// UPDATE //
For future reference, I made a typo in my `event` it should be `events`.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a typo `<div id="#click">Click</div>` should be `<div id="click">Click</div>`.

The `#` is used for selecting ids, not for id names.

Comment: Ah yes. Been working with HAML to much, but that does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: Ah geez, it's `events` not `event`. God I hate/love learning new code.